# On what conditions for ${\bf C}$, such that $trace({\bf AC}) \geq trace({\bf BC})$, given that $trace({\bf A}) \geq trace({\bf B})$?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, trace, positive-semidefinite

Edit:

Given two real symmetric matrices ${\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}$, of size $n \times n$, such that their traces satisfies $trace({\bf A}) \geq trace({\bf B})$. I wish to find a general $n \times n$ matrix ${\bf C}$, such that $trace({\bf AC}) \geq trace({\bf BC})$.

*Old question:
Given a real symmetric matrix ${\bf A} \in {\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}$, we have $A$ is positive semidefinite, i.e., ${\bf A} \succeq {\bf 0}$. I wish to find a matrix ${\bf C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, such that ${\bf AC}$ is also positive semidefinite, i.e., ${\bf AC} \succeq {\bf 0}$. Does such ${\bf C}$ exist? If yes, what conditions should it be met?
[I guess we may need to consider the rank/positive-semidefiniteness of ${\bf C}$.]*

Comment: Well, $\mathbf C = \mathbf I$ works :)

Comment: @MishaLavrov, sure, ${\bf C} = {\bf I}$ works. But I want to know more general conditions for such ${\bf C}$.

Comment: This question is too vague. Do you want conditions on $C$ such that $AC$ is pos. def. for a given $A$? Do you want to characterize all pairs $(A,C)$ with this property? Do you want to know if there is a $C$ such that $AC + C^TA = Q$ for a given pos. def. symmetric $Q$? This last problem is known as a **Lyapunov equation** and there is a closed form solution for $C$ in terms of $A$ and $Q$.

Comment: @HansEngler, thanks for your comments and questions. I had some misunderstandings with respect to the definition of positive semidefinite matrix. I though pos. def. is for any matrix, but it is actually for symmetric matrices only.

Answer (score 0):

You can deduce some conditions on $\mathbf C$ by picking some specific choices of $\mathbf A$ to see what happens.

For example, you can start by taking a matrix $\mathbf A$ with a single $1$ in some diagonal entry, and $0$ everywhere else. What is $\mathbf A\mathbf C$ in that case? When will this be positive semidefinite?

This narrows down the options for $\mathbf C$ considerably, but you will need to look at some more complicated matrices $\mathbf A$. For example, you could take nearly-zero matrices with the $2\times 2$ block $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$: in some sense, these are the next-simplest positive semidefinite matrix.

Watch out, though: in general, $\mathbf A \mathbf C$ will not be symmetric, even if $\mathbf A$ is (and even if both $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf C$ are). You can still technically say that a non-symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite, but this is not done very often; probably, what you want this to mean is that $\mathbf A \mathbf C + (\mathbf A \mathbf C)^{\mathsf T} \succeq \mathbf 0$.